# How to redirect to the page that I submit in the form (pagination)

Tags: php, forms, url, redirect, pagination

Hello I have this form:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="number" name="page=home&paginH">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I have a pagination in my code...so I want to put a field in my site like the form above, when the user write a number in the field and submit it, must redirect him to the page that the user wrote. My problem is like this... the result that I take in my URL is http://example.com/index.php?page%3Dhome%26paginH=2 The number '2' in the end is the number that user submit. The problem is that the URL changes but the page stills the same. I have searched a lot but i could not find the solution. Thanks in advance!

Yes I am sorry!

This is my php:

```
<?php
$per_page = 1;
//Ayto einai to apotelesma p 8a vgalei sto index(arxiko h home) ola ta post mazi.
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `posts`") or die(mysql_error());
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

//$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
if (isset($_GET['paginH'])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['paginH'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">No Posts Were Found</td></tr>";
    } else {
        while($post = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $article_id=$post["ID"];
            $link = "admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php";
            $var = "article_id";
            $id = $post['ID'];
            $date = $post['Date'];
            $image = $post['Image_home'];
            echo "<div class='perigrama'><div class='titlos'><h2><a href='admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php?article_id=" . $article_id . "'><span>" . $post['Title'] . "</span></a></h2></div><div class='infos'><p>Posted by <a href='#'><span>" . $post['Author'] . "</span></a> on ". $date . " | <a href='admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php?article_id=" . $article_id . "'><span>Full article</span></a></p></div><tr><td><div class='image'><img src='". $image ."' width='540' height='300'></div></td></tr><div class='content'><p>" . truncate($post['Content'],$link,$var,$id) . "</p></div><div class='more'><p><a href='admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php?article_id=" . $article_id . "'><span>Read more</span></a></p></div></div>";
        }
    }
            echo '<div class="pagination"><ul><li>';                        
            //$first = 1;
            //if ($pages >= 1) {
            //  echo '<a href="?page=home&paginH='.$first.'">First</a> ';
            //}

            $prev = ($page - 1);
            if ($page > 1) {
                echo '<a class="prevnext paginH" href="?page=home&paginH='.$prev.'"><span class="velakiaPrevNext"><<</span> Previous</a> ';
            }

            $first = 1;
            if ($page > 3) {
                if ($pages >= 1) {
                    echo '<a href="?page=home&paginH='.$first.'">1</a> ';
                } 
            }

            if ($page > 3) {
                echo ' <span>...</span> ';
            }

            if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {
                //for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
                //for ($x = $page + 0; $x <= min($page + 3, $pages); $x++) {
                for($x = max(1, $page - 2); $x <= min($page + 2, $pages); $x++) {
                //for ($x = $page + 0; $x <= max($page + 3, $pages); $x++) {
                    echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a class="currentpage" href="?page=home&paginH='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page=home&paginH='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                //}
                }   
            }
            $p = ($pages - 3);
            if ($page <= $p) {
                echo ' <span>...</span> ';
            }
            $last = $pages;
            if ($page <= $p) {
                if ($pages >= 1) {
                    echo '<a href="?page=home&paginH='.$last.'">'.$pages.'</a> ';
                }
            }

            $next = ($page + 1);
            if ($page < $pages) {
                echo '<a class="prevnext" href="?page=home&paginH='.$next.'">Next <span class="velakiaPrevNext">>></span></a> ';
            } 


            //if ($pages >= 1) {
            //  echo '<a href="?page=home&paginH='.$last.'">Last</a> ';
            //}
            echo '</li></ul></div>';




?>
```

Comment: Maybe you could share some of your PHP code for handling the `$_GET` request with us.

Comment: you are using `name` as the `value` attribute you need to give th input a `name`, and set its `value` to the page url

Comment: can you show the php code and query?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to code and after analysis the code. I suggest to you to change your form code by the following:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="home">
    <input type="number" name="paginH" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will work for you sure.

Answer (score 1):

take a hidden field with name "page" And value as "home" and then name your Input field as "paginH" and let user enter the number and submit it, when he do the form will submit to "action of form" with required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic example, you would need to sanitize the input. Plus you have your attributes wrong, you have your url in the name attribute when it should be in the value attribute, though your url looks wrong as well.

**HTML**

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="number" name="url" value="?page=home&paginH">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Php**

```
<?php

header('location: '.$_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your form like this.

```
<form name="form_submit" method="post" action="">           
   <table>
      <tr>
         <input type="hidden" name="page" value="home" />
         <td><input type="number" value="" name="paginH"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="publication" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Post values you will get like below

```
Array
(
    [page] => home
    [paginH] => 2
    [publication] => Submit
)
```